# Assigning the value from a select statement to a vairable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to SQL in general and even more so to MySQL and I've hit a stumbling block. I'm attempting to use a procedure to copy the value of one field to another if the original field is not null, this procedure is then called by triggers whenever the table is updated or has a new row inserted into it. Here is what I have so far:

```
-- WORK_NOTES_PROCEDURE - This copies the contents of the estimate notes to the work   order notes if the original estimate had any notes with it.
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS 'WORK_NOTES_PROCEDURE';
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE WORK_NOTES_PROCEDURE()
BEGIN
DECLARE var_temp VARCHAR(50);

SET var_temp := (SELECT ESTIMATE_NOTES FROM ESTIMATES WHERE ESTIMATES.ESTIMATE_NUMBER = WORK_ORDERS.ESTIMATE_NUMBER);

IF var_temp IS NOT NULL THEN

UPDATE WORK_ORDERS SET WORK_ORDER_NOTES = var_temp WHERE WORK_ORDERS.ESTIMATE NUMBER = ESTIMATES.ESTIMATE_NUMBER;

END IF; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Absolutely any help would be appreciated, the error I'm getting is a syntax error for the line where I'm assigning a value to var_temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
SET var_temp = (SELECT ESTIMATE_NOTES 
                FROM ESTIMATES INNER JOIN WORK_ORDERS
                     ON ESTIMATES.ESTIMATE_NUMBER = WORK_ORDERS.ESTIMATE_NUMBER
                LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the super speedy response, that seems to have 'moved' my error - it is now throwing a syntax error for the end of the UPDATE statement/the END IF.

Comment: Actually you can do it directly without using a variable and an `IF` statement,

`UPDATE  WORK_ORDERS a
  INNER JOIN ESTIMATES b
   ON a.ESTIMATE_NUMBER = ESTIMATES.ESTIMATE_NUMBER
SET  a.WORK_ORDER_NOTES = ESTIMATE_NOTES;`

Comment: Well whilst that does actually work in terms of making the notes from the estimates table get copied into the work orders table, the whole reason I was using the IF statement was to make sure the notes from the estimates table were only copied if they actually existed. I'm basically trying to avoid someone adding a new row to the work orders table with notes and then those notes getting overwritten by a NULL if nothing was entered for the notes in the estimates table.

Comment: the problem with your update statement is that: first, notice the space between the variable `WORK_ORDERS.ESTIMATE NUMBER`, second: if you try to fix that, another error will appear saying a column is not found `ESTIMATES.ESTIMATE_NUMBER;`.

Comment: Well I eventually got it working: I used your UPDATE statement in place of mine however I edited the line `ESTIMATES.ESTIMATE_NUMBER SET a.WORK_ORDER_NOTES = ESTIMATE_NOTES;` to be `b.ESTIMATE_NUMBER SET a.WORK_ORDER_NOTES = ESTIMATE_NOTES`. This gets rid of the issue with the column not being found. I had not spotted the mistake in the variable name though so thank you for that! I am having some issues with triggers as well but I believe I will post that as a seperate question. Thanks again!